# freemarker configuration get template by locale and template name

Tags: java, spring, localization, freemarker

My EmailHandler class is as follows:

```
Class EmailHandler {
    ...
    @Autowired
        protected Configuration config;
    }
    ...
    protected Template getTemplate(String templateName, Locale locale) throws IOException, TemplateException {
        return config.getTemplate(templateName, locale);
    }
    ...
}
```

In my applicationcontext.xml, I have

```
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/templates/email"/>
</bean>
```

my directory structure for templates is as follows:

```
--src
----main
------resources
--------templates
----------email
------------template1.ftl
------------template2.ftl
------------template3.ftl
------------template4.ftl
------------multilanguage
--------------fr
----------------template1.ftl
```

At present getTemplate is always called with (string, Locale.US). But, in future, I want to be  able to call getTemplate with (string, Locale.FR).

Following are my questions:
1. How should I change my directory structure to specify templates for french language.
2. What does config.getTemplate(templateName, locale); exactly do? How does that method find template for Locale.US in template directory?
3. I want to load my french language templates from email/multilanguage/fr directory. How do I do that?

Thanks,

Rishi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `getTemplate("foo.ftl", Locale.US)`, FreeMarker first tries to load `foo_en_US.ftl`, then `foo_en.ftl`, finally `foo.ftl`. So the French templates should be named like `foo_fr.ftl`.

The locale specified for `getTemplate` also decides what the value of the `locale` setting will be inside the template. This, however, can be overridden in the `Environment` object. That can be done if instead of `myTemplate.process(...)` you call `env = myTemplate.createProcessingEnvironment(...); env.setLocale(...); env.process()`, or in the template with `<#setting locale='...'>`.

As of loading templates from subdirectories based on the locale, you can implement a `TemplateLookupStrategy` for that (see http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/TemplateLookupStrategy.html).